# org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.wordcount.WordCountDemo does not terminate

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have launched this script and it does not end.

```
sudo ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.wordcount.WordCountDemo
```

Here is the result :

```
[cloudera@quickstart kafka_2.12-2.4.1]$ sudo ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.wordcount.WordCountDemo
[2020-04-14 13:26:36,153] WARN The configuration 'admin.retries' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2020-04-14 13:26:36,165] WARN The configuration 'admin.retry.backoff.ms' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
```

It does not end.

Is ther any solution please?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour of the [demo that you are using](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/wordcount/WordCountDemo.java) and you need to press ctrl-c to terminate the process.

---

If you want the demo to stop after five seconds you can use the [older version](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0.0/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/wordcount/WordCountDemo.java#L86-L88) of the demo that terminates after 5 seconds:

```
// usually the stream application would be running forever,
// in this example we just let it run for some time and stop since the input data is finite.
Thread.sleep(5000L);
```